# Using setTimeout and clearTimeout to Cycle Through Hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a working version of my code here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/brianrhea/5Hqs3/1/

When I hover over a link, it displays a hidden div in another area of the page exactly as I would like it to.

But, if the user doesn't take any action, I'd like the hidden divs to automatically cycle through one at a time. (and having the associated link become bold just as if they were hovered over it)

If a user then hovers over the links, the cycling quits and the hover states take over. When their mouse leaves, the cycling begins again.

I've looked in to setTimeout / clearTimeout as I think that'd be the solution, but with no luck.

Working version at jsfiddle:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/brianrhea/5Hqs3/1/

```
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="billing" href="#">Billing Reminders</a><br />
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="collections" href="#">Collections</a><br />
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="payments" href="#">Payments</a>
<br /><br />

<div id="defaultMessage">
Default Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div id="textMessages">

<div class="hidden" id="billing">
Billing ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id ligula eget purus</div>

<div class="hidden" id="collections">
Collections Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="payments">
Payments orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".sliderLinks").hover(
              function(){
                  var id = $(this).data("id");
                  if(id!==undefined){
                   $("#" + id).fadeIn(500);
                  }
                  $("#textMessages").fadeIn(500);
                  $("#defaultMessage").hide();

              },function(){
                  $("#textMessages").hide();
                  $(".hidden").hide();
                  $("#defaultMessage").fadeIn(500);  
              });
      });
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to setTimeout or clearTimeout - is something missing?

Comment: I tried to do $(".sliderLinks:first").mouseover() but that did not do what I hoped so I did not continue...

Comment: @poi that is the question posed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5Hqs3/6/)]**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var i = 0;
     var links = $(".sliderLinks");
     var len = links.length;
     var interval;    

     function hoverIn(target, clear) {
        if (clear) {
            links.removeClass('hoverBold');
            $(".hidden").hide();
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
        var id = $(target).data("id");
        if(id) {
           $("#" + id).fadeIn(500);
        }
        $("#textMessages").fadeIn(500);
        $("#defaultMessage").hide();
    }    

    function hoverOut(start) {
        $("#textMessages").hide();
        $(".hidden").hide();
        $("#defaultMessage").fadeIn(500);
        if (start) {
            startCycle();
        }
    }   

    links.hover(
        function(){ hoverIn(this, true); },
        function(){ hoverOut(true); }
    );

    function startCycle() {
        i = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            hoverOut();
            hoverIn(links[i]);
            var prev = (i-1 < 0) ? len-1 : i-1;
            $(links[i]).addClass('hoverBold');
            $(links[prev]).removeClass('hoverBold');
            if (++i >= len) {
              i = 0;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    startCycle();
  });
```

Comment: No problem. :) I've also added the `font-weight: bold` part.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually bugging it up, so that now when you hover there isn't bold text. Would it be possible to use .css to add a class? That way if I also wanted to change text size, color, padding, etc I could control all of those? I created a .hoverBold class and modified $(links[i]).addClass('hoverBold'); ...it works the first time it cycles through Billing, Collections, but doesn't work on the third link or any subsequent cycle

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/brianrhea/5Hqs3/5/ Galambalazs, I've updated that to use addClass / removeClass on the link text. However, you'll see that when one of the links gets a hover, the previous bold text from cycling isn't cleared. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think setInterval will do the job better. Create an array of your three links and a corresponding array of your three divs. Now a counter var which is set to 0. In the setInterval function, do counter = (counter+1)%3, and use that to determine which div to display (and hide all others) and which link to make bold (and unbold all others). Then use clearInterval on hover for any of the links. Sorted.